# Word that means "to gain by treachery."

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm writing an outline for an assignment in which I have to write a sequel to "The Cask of Amontillado." In the introduction I have:

> Montresor has thieved and murdered his way to being the dictator of a small city state.

But "thieved" is not the right word. He isn't a thief, he is a treacherous calculating backstabber. I've been looking but can't find a word that means "to gain by treachery" and could replace "thieved."

Comment: *Schemed* or *connived*, perhaps? Even *tricked* would do.

Comment: 'usurped the government of a small city state by theft and murder'?

Comment: ... *Manipulated*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about "cheat" or one of its synonyms?

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/cheat?s=t

Swindle, trick, etc.

Comment: I think I'll use "conned." It's not my original idea but it fits best. Thanks!